# ServiceStack AutoQuery MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, servicestack

I'm experimenting with ServiceStack in MVC, using standard server side controllers creating view models. There are no jquery calls (or any direct calls) to any of the services registered at /api. Since SS lets us resolve services directly using:

```
using (var dr = HostContext.ResolveService<DataReportService>(base.HttpContext))
```

I haven't been calling the services using JsonServiceClient. Instead I've been resolving the services and calling their methods directly.

```
var dataReport = new DataReport
{
   IsArchived = false,
   ReportDate = DateTime.Now,
   ReportType = Model.ReportType
};
var drId = dr.Post(dataReport);
```

However, I have not been able to find a way to do this with the new AutoQuery feature. I know it creates a service automatically for any class that descends from QueryBase but I have had no luck resolving it. If I try to resolve the name used at run time then I won't compile (obviously). If I try something like this

```
using (var dr = HostContext.ResolveService<AutoQueryServiceBase>(base.HttpContext))
```

then it won't work either, because that is just a base class and not the actual registered instance. I know I could do this from JsonServiceClient but I'd really like to experiment with the direct call approach. Creating my own service that wraps any AutoQuery would work but seems like it defeats the purpose of the automatic creation. Still, I don't see any other way to proceed. Would love to hear any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using the `ResolveService<T>` method to get the service and call the executing method yourself, you can use `HostContext.ServiceController.Execute` method which allows you pass in the request DTO which will execute on the action method.

```cs
var dataReport = new DataReport
{
   IsArchived = false,
   ReportDate = DateTime.Now,
   ReportType = Model.ReportType
};
var drId = HostContext.ServiceController.Execute(dataReport);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: @Scott When I use HostContext.ServiceController.Execute it doesn't seem to have access to the existing session. Does this mean I have to pass in any session variables manually?

Comment: @vonec The `Execute` method has an optional second argument, that takes the HTTP Request, `httpReq`. Passing this will allow you to access the session. `HostContext.ServiceController.Execute(requestDto, httpReq)`